# Embedded Google+ Hangout in Android Application

Tags: android, google-plus, google-hangouts

I'm trying to embedded a video call provided from google hangout in my own android app.

I don't if this is possible, but i've done a lot of research and couldn't find anything.

Well someone can give me a tip how i can do this or with what other third-party i can do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this for hangout:

```
        Uri imUri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("imto").authority("gtalk")
                .appendPath("example@gmail.com").build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, imUri);

        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.talk",
                "com.google.android.talk.SigningInActivity"));

        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For video hangout you could use this:

```
Intent sky = new Intent( 
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/107117483540235115863"));
startActivity(sky);
```